# What do these cytoscape edge_bend values mean?

Tags: segment, cytoscape

When I use bending of edge in cytoscape 3.7.0 and export it to xgmml I get the below values:

```
<att name="EDGE_BEND" value="0.44096125472713704,0.8975261399143031,0.5880688839306581" type="string" cy:type="String"/>
```

I tried to figure out what it means, such as distance to start or target node, radius, weight, but I cannot understand the logic behind these values.

Could someone clearly explain me what they mean?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to edit those manually, but here is the API:

This defines collection of “handles”

http://chianti.ucsd.edu/cytoscape-3.0.1/API/org/cytoscape/view/presentation/property/values/Bend.html#getAllHandles()

And this returns actual handle positions to string.

http://chianti.ucsd.edu/cytoscape-3.6.0/API/org/cytoscape/view/presentation/property/values/Handle.html

And each handle is defined like this:

https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape-impl/blob/93530ef3b35511d9b1fe0d0eb913ecdcd3b456a8/ding-impl/ding-presentation-impl/src/main/java/org/cytoscape/ding/impl/HandleImpl.java#L247